# In Symfony2 with Doctrine, I want to only get records that do not have a related record

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have an entity Person with a OneToOne relationship with FooBar, where FooBar is nullable.

```
class Person
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Acme\MyBundle\Entity\FooBar", inversedBy="person")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="foo_bar_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $foo_bar;
}

class FooBar
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Person", mappedBy="foo_bar")
     */
    protected $person;
}
```

I would like to use querybuilder to get all the people that do not have any foobars. I was trying to do this

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->innerJoin('p.foo_bar', 'fb', 'WITH', 'fb.id IS NULL');
```

But that doesn't return any results, and I know I have some people without foobars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first left join, then restrict. Your innerJoin just won't work like that.

Something like (I can't syntax check right now);

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');

$qb->leftJoin('p.foo_bar', 'fb')
        ->where($qb->expr()->isNull('fb'))
        ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Should do the trick. You might need an addSelect in there for the fb alias as well.